# Linear Algebra: Find Matrix with Specified Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling with this problem:

Find a matrix A whose kernel consists of all points in the plane $x + 2y + 3z$ = 0.

I'm thinking the vector $[1, 2, 3]$ is perpendicular to any vector in the specified plane.  Not really sure where to go from there though...

Am hoping once I get help for this one, the same question but for kernel = line spanned by given vector will be easy.

Thanks for the help,
Mariogs

Comment: The matrix $[1\ 2 \ 3]$ is a fine example.

Comment: Is there a more systematic way of going about this?

Comment: $$ax+by+cz=0\iff (1 \ 2 \ 3)\pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = 0$$
If more equations need to be satisfied you just add the corresponding coefficients as rows to a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the vector $[1\quad 2\quad 3]^T$  is in the dual space of the kernel of $A$ which is the range space of $A^T$.

Comment: We haven't covered transpose or "dual space" yet...We've gone through 3.3 of Brettscher's text.  Also, in case I wasn't clear, I need to ensure that the kernel consists *just* of points in the specified plane, no more, no less.  Thanks again.